# FIWARE - IDAS: Issue with create new a device OMA-LWM2M

Tags: iot, fiware, agent, fiware-orion

I am really new in IDAS field.
I want to create new device as the following instruction (http://docs.telefonicaiotiotagents.apiary.io/#reference/configuration-api/devices/create-a-device)
but i have got the error with description as follow:

```
{
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND"
}
```

Environment: FIWARE - IDAS using OMA-LWM2M agent with Coap protocol.

I don't know what i should do in this case?

Comment: Which the request you send?